# How to transfer Candy Machine Authority?

Tags: metaplex, sugar, metaboss

How do we transfer Candy Machine Authority and the collection NFT authority to a new wallet? Want to keep this on a Ledger after the Candy Machine is created.

Do we need to use Metaboss for this? https://metaboss.rs/set.html#set-update-authority-all

Comment: Error running command (re-run needed): Candy Machine Error: NoChangingAuthorityWithCollection: Can't change authority while collection is enabled. Disable collection first. I am getting that error every time I run the sugar update -n NEW_PUBKEY command. I also tried to re-run after changing all the minted NFT to the new auth key using metaboss. Any ideas?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://solana.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://solana.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/2614)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to change the authority of a candy machine created using sugar you just have to use `sugar update --new-authority NEW_PUBKEY`. This will change the authority of the Candy Machine and the authority of all the unminted NFTs (when someone mints one of these NFTs will have the new authority) but won't change the authority of already minted NFTs.

If you Candy Machine has a collection attached, then it's really probable that this collection NFT will have the old authority, so you will have to update the authority of the Collection NFT (you can use metaboss as you said), and also you will need that to update all the NFTs that were minted before the Authority update.

If you change the CM authority, but you don't change the authority of the collection NFT then everyone who tries to mint that CM will have an error because both authorities don't match.